# Sent Items show HTML code when seen in Outlook while sending mail using Gmail API

Tags: php, email, outlook, gmail, google-workspace

I am trying to send mail using Gmail API using PHP. My sending "from email" is a Gmail account which is opened on **MS Outlook 2016** App on Windows. The emails sent show properly in Inbox of receivers, but in Sent items on Outlook, it shows HTML code like < p >< span style="color:red" >Hi, </ span ></ p > and so on.
I use following code to send mails:

```
$objGMail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$strMailContent = $msg;
$strToMail = $to;
$strSesFromName = $actual_fromname;
$strSesFromEmail = $actual_fromemail; 
$strSubject = $subject; 
$strRawMessage .= 'To: ' . $strToMailName . " <" . $strToMail . ">" . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'From: ' . $strSesFromName . " <" . $strSesFromEmail . ">" . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?' . $subjectCharset . '?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
  
$strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; ' . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= $strMailContent . "\r\n";
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage) , '+/', '-_') , '=');
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
$objSentMsg = $objGMail
  ->users_messages
  ->send($actual_fromemail, $msg);
```

We tried changing settings in outlook app as well.
Can anyone let me know why can't the actual message display instead of HTML code in Sent items?

Comment: If the only place you've noticed this issue is in "Sent items" in your (6 years old) Outlook application, then I would chalk it down as an Outlook bug and move on.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yes, only on the Sent items on my client's Outlook application. If we send mail from another gmail account and view it on Gmail app, it works fine.

Comment: Have you checked the result HTML markup of the sent and received emails?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes the HTML is ok. When we view that in Inbox in Gmail it works fine.

Comment: Did you have a chance to compare the HTML markup in Outlook and Gmail? How does it look like?

Comment: So, in gmail the view of HTML is properly visible with headings, paragraphs, images, etc all rendered but in Outlook it shows HTML code like : <p><span>Hi, </span><span></span><img src=""></p>